# When each of joining particles ～や～ and ～とか～ should be used?

Tags: grammar, usage

What is the difference between　～や～ and ～とか～ joining particles? 
For example:

> 1) 飲み物やカップや～ 
> 2) 飲み物とかカップとか～

It looks like the meaning is about the same of both sentences.. When each of particles ～や～ and ～とか～ should be used?

---

明けましておめでとうございます！
^^

Comment: Perhaps a sentence such as the following might shed some light on these two particles: 「桃**や**洋ナシ**や**リンゴ**とか**のフレッシュな果実味が広がる。」

Comment: Yes indeed, but the question is not answered completely.. I still can not understand when/in what situation each particle should be used.

Comment: @istrasci The answer in that question is not so clear, and it would be helpful to have some good examples.

Comment: The solution in that case is to offer a bounty for a better answer there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) 飲み物やカップや～
>   2) 飲み物とかカップとか～

2 is more colloquial and casual.

> 3) 桃や洋ナシやリンゴなどのフルーツ味
>   4) 桃や洋ナシやリンゴとかのフルーツ味
>   5) 桃とか洋ナシとかリンゴとかのフルーツ味

3 is the most literary and 5 is the most colloquial.

(You can say 桃や洋ナシやりんごなど/とか + の/が/をetc. but not 桃や洋ナシやりんご**や** + の/が/をetc.)

Comment: In formal writing such as newspaper articles or academic papers, I think 「桃や洋ナシ、リンゴ、バナナ などの/のような/などのような フルーツ味」 or 「桃や洋ナシ、リンゴ、バナナといった(ような)フルーツ味」 etc. would be preferred, avoiding a repetition of や.